Bash script that chooses a different file every script call?
I am trying to have a bash script that has a sequence of files in a directory and chooses 1 of them and outputs it to the terminal. Then on the next run, it chooses the next file in the sequence and outputs that file's name. Is it possible to do that? How can I have the bash program "remember" what file it chose to then choose the next one on the next script call?

use a text file to remember things

That was my first thought. However, is there a better way without needing an external file? I don't have an issue doing so but I wanted to make sure there is another way.

Environmental/etc variable? Or, more dangerously, have the script over-write itself?

What if the latest file is deleted, renamed or the directory contents change?

use a database such as sqlite ... it indirectly uses an external file, but it gives you an advantage of being able to sort the data and to remember multiple facts

A simple way: at the end of the script add an mv command to move the file to another directory.

Use a moving softlink.
Initialize:
ln -s file001 .thisone

In your script:
infile="$(stat -c "%N" .thisone)"
sequence=$( basename "$infile"  | sed -e 's%file0*%%' )
next=$((sequence + 1))
printf -v nextfile "file%03d" $next
rm -f .thisone
if [[ -f "$nextfile" ]] ; then
    ln -s "$nextfile" .thisone
else
    ln -s "file001" .thisone
fi
#
# process $infile, .thisone next

UNTESTED, but shellcheck.net likes it.
